# Add Class via Javascript (PHP Loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are many questions on this however none worked for me.

```
for($u = 0; $u < count($pui); $u++ ){
  echo '<li id="catso_'.$u.'" class="btn" value="'.trim($pui[$u]['category_id']).'" onclick="moveCategory(this.value);">'.trim($pui[$u]['category_name']).'</li>'; }
```

In the above code I want to add `active` class on the links which have been clicked.

Jquery Code:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
   $('.nav li').addClass('active');
     $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

I have a function called on onclick `onclick="moveCategory(this.value);"` However i.e. to pass the values in the textbox; hope that is not conflicting with the jquery function.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Utpal

Comment: If I understood question correctly then you have to remove class from every li and add into clicked one like `$('.nav li').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');` may help this...

Comment: `onclick="moveCategory(this.value);"` is not going to pass in the attribute `value`'s value. You would need to use `this.getAttribute("value")` or similar

Comment: Hey Debin thanks for the reply however this is not quite working.

Comment: Patrick; that is not the question. `moveCategory(this.value);` is working just fine. Was wondering if it is not conflicting with `$('.nav').on('click',... `

Answer (score 0):

prefer using the li id in the event handler to change active class

```
  $(document).on("click", "li[id*='catso_']", function(){
     //get the loop value to speficy the pressed li
       var id= this.id.replace('catso_','');  
     $('#catso_'+id).addClass('active');
       //if you want to remove all other active   
       $('.btn:not(#catso_'+id+')').removeClass('active');  //!fixed
    });
```